# Would chmod 000 /dev/stdin disable terminal forever?

Tags: terminal, devices, chmod

I'm working through questions from [Unix The Textbook](https://www.amazon.ca/Unix-Textbook-Syed-Mansoor-Sarwar/dp/032122731X) *(chapter 8, #16, page 207)*:

> Give `chmod` command lines that perform the same tasks that the `mesg
>   n` and `mesg y` commands do. (Hint: Every hardware device, including
>   your terminal, has an associated file in the `/dev` directory.)

I believe the answer is:

`mesg n` = `chmod 770 /dev/stdout`

`mesg y` = `chmod 777 /dev/stdout`

But I was wondering what happens if you use `chmod 000 /dev/stdin`?

Do you get locked out of entering commands in the terminal?

Comment: It's important to understand that permissions are only checked when a file is opened.  Therefore, no matter what your shell's standard input happens to be, changing its permissions won't lock you out of entering commands, because both the shell and the terminal emulator or ssh or whatever have already opened the communications channel.  `mesg n` can use permissions to affect future `write`s only because `write` _doesn't_ already have the terminal open.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout` are the wrong device. These are not terminal devices, they're aliases for standard input and standard output respectively. Standard input and standard output are, by definition, [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) that applications expect to be open and have a conventional meaning (file descriptor 0 and 1 respectively, there's also 2 which is standard error). Devices such as `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout` are useful when an application requires a file name, but the user of the application wants it to access a particular file descriptor rather than opening some file. Depending on the unix variant, they might not even be device files; for example, on Linux, they're symbolic links to `/proc/self/fd/0` and friends, and these are in turn “magic” symbolic links to whatever file the process has already open on that file descriptor.

Changing the permissions of `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout` would only change what happens when these file names are used explicitly. It doesn't affect anything related to the terminal, and it doesn't affect normal use of standard input and standard output, since the permissions only matter when opening a particular filename.

What `mesg` does is to change the permissions of the process's **controlling terminal**. For an application that's running in a terminal, the terminal is open on standard input, standard ouput and standard error (file descriptors 0, 1 and 2). You can use the command `tty` to see what the terminal device is. `mesg n` is equivalent to `chmod g-w "$(tty)"` and `mesg y` is equivalent to `chmod g+w "$(tty)"`.

Comment: `tty` doesn't report the controlling terminal, but the terminal open on stdin if any. So on Linux where /dev/stdin is not a device but a special symlink to the file open on /dev/stdin, `chmot "$(tty)"` would be more or less the same as `chmod /dev/stdin` (if stdin is a tty device, and would attempt to change the mode of a `not a tty` file in the current directory otherwise). See `/dev/$(ps -o tty= -p "$$")` for the controlling terminal.